# PuTTY Alternative with keyboard copy/paste

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, putty

I'm looking an some alternative for PuTTY, in which you can select, copy, and paste text, using only the keyboard.

Does anyone know anything like this?

Answer (score 4):

This question has already been answered in detail [here](https://superuser.com/questions/85772/putty-how-to-select-text-and-copy-text-using-keyboard-only) - please do a search next time.

Comment: i'm looking for PuTTY ALTERNATIVE that can do that, BECAUSE it cannot be done with putty.

Comment: If you'd take the time to read all the answers, you'd see that some alternatives are actually given, as well as some workarounds with PuTTY.

Comment: Shift+Delete copies from putty, Shift+Insert pastes.  There isn't an alternative for selecting text without the mouse but in the other answer there is a copy-all option mentioned

Comment: @adavea.. agreed.. However, I think most people who are asking this question are looking for a keyboard only option. We are using VIM to improve coding efficiency.. so want to get away from the mouse. if we use shift+delete or Cntrl+Insert, we have to use mouse to copy.. so we can just use left click anyway to copy..

Comment: @adavea, I am compiling a list of potential options here.. though I started with the same question above.., from all the answers I have read here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45271895/.. if you know anything better please mention it so we can reduce such questions and make it easier for newcomers to get to the answers quicker. As it stands right now, it took me a while to get to this page..

Comment: @Gant, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45271895/

Answer (score 1):

**SSH Secure Shell** or
try **SSH Editor**

Comment: can you provide some links. Are you talking about anything from here: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/download/

Comment: where can I ssh editor? Google search doesnt lead to anything https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+secure+editor&oq=ssh+secure+editor

Answer (score 0):

In [kitty](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/) at least the backspace key works opposite to putty!

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>INS</kbd> works to insert text.

I think an Autohotkey script could help in general, like the one for the CMD in Windows enabling CTRL+V. However, I could not find a putty/kitty script. Probably you can adapt the existing one:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
^V::
SendInput {Raw}%clipboard%
return
#IfWinActive
```

Marking text by SHIFT and CURSOR keys might not work, I assume.