# How to copy a screen area in PuTTY without pasting?

Tags: putty, copy-paste

My usual method of copying a screen area in PuTTY is via the right-click button, but also has the effect of pasting as well, resulting in entering a sequence of meaningless commands or pasting the text in an editor.

Is there another of copying which doesn't entail pasting as well?

Comment: It turns out that by selecting the area with the mouse and just releasing the mouse button the area get's copied- discovered here - http://superuser.com/questions/85772/putty-how-to-select-text-and-copy-text-using-keyboard-only, so much for my PuTTY skills as a long term user

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out to be much simply than I thought. When you highlight an area with the mouse, selected it and release the button, it is automatically copied on to the clipboard. I have been so hung up of copying and pasting via the right click button that I did not know of this simple option.

Answer from [PuTTY how to select text and copy text using keyboard ONLY](https://superuser.com/questions/85772/putty-how-to-select-text-and-copy-text-using-keyboard-only)