# How to copy long text from PuTTY to text document in Windows?

Tags: windows, putty, clipboard

Following this question [PuTTY how to select text and copy text using keyboard ONLY](https://superuser.com/questions/85772/putty-how-to-select-text-and-copy-text-using-keyboard-only?newreg=0e87a7d6c7b449f8b0573198610507cc)

I need to copy a very long text and paste it in another file (not in PuTTY)
I can only copy chunks... It doesn't let me to mark the whole file (or <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> equivalent). What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do:

- *Clear Scrollback* (in PuTTY window title bar context [right-click] menu)
- *Reset Terminal* (or `clear` command or equivalent)
- display file, e.g.

  ```
  cat myfile
  ```
- *Copy All to Clipboard*

You will obviously still get at least the `cat myfile` command in the clipboard, but you can easily remove that after pasting.