# How do I copy from Putty on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, copy-paste, raspbian

This is slightly different than [older](https://superuser.com/questions/1186035/how-to-copy-all-text-in-edited-file-from-putty-to-clipboard) [questions](https://superuser.com/questions/85772/putty-how-to-select-text-and-copy-text-using-keyboard-only) about PuTTY.  I have a Raspberry Pi and am using PuTTY to connect the Pi to another machine over a serial connection.

While it is possible to drag the mouse over PuTTY's window to select and copy the text, this tedious and error prone.  Is there a way to select all of the text in PuTTY's window?  There are no window controls that might allow me to automatically select all of the text and it is not a terminal window.

I am running "Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)" on a Raspberry Pi 3, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and right-click the PuTTY window (not on the titlebar) and select **Copy All** from the menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try right-clicking on the title bar of PuTTY and selecting "Copy All to Clipboard". That should copy all of the text inside the PuTTY window to your clipboard.